# Make USB device visible with different vendor and product ID

Tags: usb, emulation, device-emulation

I'm looking for a way to make a USB device show up as if it has different vendor and product IDs. I'm trying to make a proprietary piece of software to work with a USB device that should be supported but gets rejected solely because of its ID.

The software is for Windows, but I can run it in a VM in Linux. So I'll be fine with either approach, whatever works:

- Changing USB ID in Linux
- Changing USB ID in Windows
- Making Qemu (or perhaps some other equivalent) change USB ID in passthrough

Answer (score 1):

There may be a simpler way to do this, but I was faced with a similar problem and was able to create a process in which I could change the device descriptor information for development purposes. The process is summarized in this diagram: [image]

First configure a static IP address for you Raspberry Pi and configure your PC ethernet TCP/IPv4 settings so you are able to communicate with you Raspberry Pi over the LAN connection.

Download the Virtual Here Raspberry Pi server and the client software for your PC from the Virtual Here [website](https://virtualhere.com/usb_server_software). The trial version will work for this use case.

Move the Virtual Here server software to you Raspberry Pi. In order to run the USB server you need to change the privileges of the file with  `$ sudo chmod +x vhusbdarm` then run with `$ sudo ./vhusbdarm`.

Run the client software on your local machine. You will see that the client detects the USB device on the USB device server at `<Your Raspberry Pi IP address>:7575`. Connecting to the device at this point will give no advantage and mimic a direct connection.

Run the python file bellow, which was modified from a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61706643/9963753), but utilizes Scapy sniff to capture the incoming packets before forwarding the raw data. The original script in the linked solution should work fine as well. In the script you can see that I used port `12345`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
import socket
import threading
import select
from queue import Queue
main_queue = Queue()

terminateAll = False

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, clientSocket, targetHost, targetPort):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__clientSocket = clientSocket
        self.__targetHost = targetHost
        self.__targetPort = targetPort

    def run(self):
        print("Client Thread started")

        self.__clientSocket.setblocking(0)

        targetHostSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        targetHostSocket.connect((self.__targetHost, self.__targetPort))
        targetHostSocket.setblocking(0)

        clientData = b""
        targetHostData = b""
        terminate = False
        while not terminate and not terminateAll:
            inputs = [self.__clientSocket, targetHostSocket]
            outputs = []

            if len(clientData) > 0:
                outputs.append(self.__clientSocket)

            if len(targetHostData) > 0:
                outputs.append(targetHostSocket)

            try:
                inputsReady, outputsReady, errorsReady = select.select(inputs, outputs, [], 1.0)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break

            for inp in inputsReady:
                if inp == self.__clientSocket:
                    try:
                        data = self.__clientSocket.recv(4096)
                        #print(data)
                        #data = b""
                        #while not main_queue.empty():
                        #    data += main_queue.get()
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

                    if data != None:
                        if len(data) > 0:
                            targetHostData += data
                        #else:
                        #    terminate = True
                elif inp == targetHostSocket:
                    try:
                        data = b""
                        while not main_queue.empty():
                           data += main_queue.get()
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

                    if data != None:
                        if len(data) > 0:
                            clientData += data

            for out in outputsReady:
                if out == self.__clientSocket and len(clientData) > 0:
                    #pck = Ether(clientData)
                    #pck.show()
                    bytesWritten = self.__clientSocket.send(clientData)
                    if bytesWritten > 0:
                        clientData = clientData[bytesWritten:]
                elif out == targetHostSocket and len(targetHostData) > 0:
                    #pck = Ether(targetHostData)
                    #pck.show()
                    bytesWritten = targetHostSocket.send(targetHostData)
                    if bytesWritten > 0:
                        targetHostData = targetHostData[bytesWritten:]

        self.__clientSocket.close()
        targetHostSocket.close()
        print ("ClientThread terminating")


def handle_sniff(pck):
    if IP in pck:
        if pck[IP].src == "192.168.1.48":
            if Raw in pck:
                payload = pck[Raw].load
                if b'\x12\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08$\x07\x04\x00\x88#\x01\x02\x00\x01' in payload:
                    payload = payload.replace(b'\x00\x08$\x07\x04\x00\x88#\x01\x02\x00', b'\x00\x08$\x07\x04\x00\x88\x15\x01\x02\x00')
                    
                print(payload)
                main_queue.put(payload)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    localHost = "localhost"
    localPort = 12345
    targetHost = "192.168.1.12"
    targetPort = 7575

    serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind((localHost, localPort))
    serverSocket.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for client...")
    while True:
        try:
            clientSocket, address = serverSocket.accept()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nTerminating...")
            terminateAll = True
            break
        print("starting client")
        ClientThread(clientSocket, targetHost, targetPort).start()
        sniff(iface="Ethernet", prn=lambda pck: handle_sniff(pck))

    serverSocket.close()
```

Once the script is running, configure the Virtual Here client to listen for USB servers at `localhost:12345`. The `handle_sniff` function is where the USB device descriptor information is being changed. Once connected you should be able to double click on the USB device in the dropdown tree. You will see the USB data begin to be printed in the your python console.

In the above example I changed the device bcdDevice bytes of the USB Descriptor.

Another helpful script I used to identify the packet that contained the information I was targeting is below. I modified a script I found in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24756591/9963753). It is modified to print the raw data along with the unpacked device descriptor information, which can then be searched for in the TCP raw data to identify which bytes to replace.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import string
import struct
import sys

import win32api
import win32file
import pywintypes

BUFF=b""
def CTL_CODE(DeviceType, Function, Method, Access):
    return (DeviceType << 16) | (Access << 14) | (Function << 2) | Method
def USB_CTL(id):
   # CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_USB, (id), METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
    return CTL_CODE(0x22, id, 0, 0)

IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME = USB_CTL(258)                   # HCD_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME
IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION = USB_CTL(258)                # USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION
IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION = USB_CTL(259)     # USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION
IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_DRIVERKEY_NAME = USB_CTL(264)  # USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_DRIVERKEY_NAME
IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_NAME = USB_CTL(261)            # USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_NAME
IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION = USB_CTL(260) # USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION

USB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE = 2
USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE = 3
USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE = 4
MAXIMUM_USB_STRING_LENGTH = 255


def open_dev(name):
    try:
        handle = win32file.CreateFile(name,
                                  win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                  win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                  None,
                                  win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                  0,
                                  None)
    except pywintypes.error as e:
        return None
    return handle


def get_root_hub_name(handle):
    buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME,
                                None,
                                6,
                                None)
    act_len, _ = struct.unpack('LH', buf)
    buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME,
                                None,
                                act_len,
                                None)
    return buf[4:].decode('utf-16le')


def get_driverkey_name(handle, index):
    key_name = bytes(chr(index) + '\0'*9, 'utf-8')
    try:
        buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                    IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_DRIVERKEY_NAME,
                                    key_name,
                                    10,
                                    None)
    except pywintypes.error as e:
        print(e.strerror, index)
        sys.exit(1)
    _, act_len, _ = struct.unpack('LLH', buf)
    buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_DRIVERKEY_NAME,
                                key_name,
                                act_len,
                                None)
    return buf[8:].decode('utf-16le')


def get_ext_hub_name(handle, index):
    hub_name = chr(index) + '\0'*9
    buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_NAME,
                                hub_name,
                                10,
                                None)
    _, act_len, _ = struct.unpack('LLH', buf)
    buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_NAME,
                                hub_name,
                                act_len,
                                None)
    return buf[8:].decode('utf-16le')


def get_str_desc(handle, conn_idx, str_idx):
    req = struct.pack('LBBHHH',
                  conn_idx,
                  0,
                  0,
                  (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE<<8) | str_idx,
                  win32api.GetSystemDefaultLangID(),
                  MAXIMUM_USB_STRING_LENGTH)
    try:
        buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                    IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION,
                                    req,
                                    12+MAXIMUM_USB_STRING_LENGTH,
                                    None)
    except pywintypes.error as e:
         return 'ERROR: no String Descriptor for index {}'.format(str_idx)
    if len(buf) > 16:
        return buf[14:].decode('utf-16le')
    return ''


def exam_hub(name, verbose, level):
    handle = open_dev(r'\\.\{}'.format(name))
    if not handle:
        print('Failed to open device {}'.format(name))
        return
    buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION,
                                None,
                                76,
                                None)
    print_hub_ports(handle, ord(buf[6]), verbose, level)
    handle.close()


def print_str_or_hex(to_be_print):
    if all(c in string.printable for c in to_be_print):
        print('"{}"'.format(to_be_print))
        return
    print('Hex: ', end='')
    for x in to_be_print:
        print('{:02x} '.format(ord(x)), end='')
    print('')


def print_hub_ports(handle, num_ports, verbose, level):
    print(handle, num_ports, verbose, level)
    for idx in range(1, num_ports+1):
        info = bytes(chr(idx) + '\0'*34, 'utf-8')
        try:
            buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                        IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION,
                                        info,
                                        34 + 11*30,
                                        None)
        except pywintypes.error as e:
            print(e)
            print(e.winerror, e.funcname, e.strerror)
            return
        print(buf)
        _, vid, pid, vers, manu, prod, seri, _, ishub, _, stat = struct.unpack('=12sHHHBBB3s?6sL', buf[:35])

        if ishub:
            if verbose:
                print('{}  [Port{}] {}'.format('  '*level, idx, 'USB Hub'))
            exam_hub(get_ext_hub_name(handle, idx), verbose, level)
        elif stat == 0 and verbose:
            print('{}  [Port{}] {}'.format('  '*level, idx, 'NoDeviceConnected'))
        elif stat == 1:
            if verbose or (manu != 0 or prod != 0 or seri != 0):
                print('{}  [Port{}] {}'.format('  '*level, idx, get_driverkey_name(handle, idx)))
                print('{}    Vendor ID:    0x{:04X}'.format('  '*level, vid))
                print('{}    Product ID:  0x{:04X}'.format('  '*level, pid))
                print('{}    Device BCD:  0x{:04X}'.format('  '*level, vers))
                print(vers)
                if manu != 0:
                    print('{}    Manufacturer (0x{:x}) -> '.format('  '*level, manu), end='')
                    print_str_or_hex(get_str_desc(handle, idx, manu))
                if prod != 0:
                    print('{}    Product      (0x{:x}) -> '.format('  '*level, prod), end='')
                    print_str_or_hex(get_str_desc(handle, idx, prod))
                if seri != 0:
                    print('{}    Serial No    (0x{:x}) -> '.format('  '*level, seri), end='')
                    print_str_or_hex(get_str_desc(handle, idx, seri))


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true',
                    help="Increase output verbosity.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    for i in range(10):
        name = r"\\.\HCD{}".format(i)
        handle = open_dev(name)
        if not handle:
            continue

        root = get_root_hub_name(handle)
        print('{}RootHub: {}'.format('\n' if i != 0 else '', root))

        dev_name = r'\\.\{}'.format(root)
        dev_handle = open_dev(dev_name)
        if not dev_handle:
            print('Failed to open device {}'.format(dev_name))
            continue

        buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(dev_handle,
                                    IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION,
                                    None,
                                    76,
                                    None)
        global BUFF
        BUFF=buf
        print_hub_ports(dev_handle, buf[6], args.verbose, 0)
        dev_handle.close()
        handle.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

P.S. This is also really helpful for filtering and modifying any of the USB data being transferred not just the device descriptor.